# Hibernate inheritance, duplicate ID's in two different tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent");
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public class Parent {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ME_SEQ", sequenceName = "ME_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ME_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(38,0)", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
}
```

There is also a child entity (seperate table) **which has a PK and FK that points to Parent ID**.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

Even though there is two separated tables, I get an error from Hibernate:

> org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

Is it not possible to have ID in the child class, even if it's a different table from the parent?

Comment: Your Child class extends Parent. So a Child **is a** Parent. A Parent is identified by its id field. Since a Child **is a** parent, it's identified by the same ID. The Child class must not have another ID field. It already has one, defined in the Parent class.

Comment: The database model cannot be changed, so this is impossible to achieve?

Comment: Why would you need to change the database model? A Child is a parent. Parents have an ID stored in the PARENT_ID column. A child is stored in the child table. A child **is a** parent. So if you have a parent_id column in the child table, everything is fine.

Comment: Which two IDs? The parent's ID field is mapped to the PARENT_ID colun. The Child's ID field that you have defined (but shouldn't have) is also mapped to the same column PARENT_ID. So, which two IDs are you talking about? What are you trying to achieve? If you think a child should have a different ID from a parent, then a Child must not be a Parent.

Comment: There is two tables in the database. The parent table with a PARENT_ID (PK) [ID 1], there is also a child table with a PARENT_ID (PK, FK) [ID 2]. I am trying to achieve inheritance with the current database model.

Comment: Just remove the useless ID field from the Child class. It's useless, as I said several times already. The ID is **already** defined in the Parent class.

Comment: That error is completely unrelated to your question and to the code you posted.